# iOS app shows default firemonkey image, How can i change iOS app Splash Screen?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

i use Delphi 10.4.2, MacOS 11, xCode 12.4 and ios 14.

i set splash screen (launch image) but my app shows firemonkey image. How can i configure splash screen for iOS app? Whats the size of 2x and 3x launch image?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please expand your question by showing the expected result as well as the result you are not satisfied with. Possibly show any log file passages where the error message is contained.  Last but not least, show us your efforts that were unsuccessful.

Comment: You mean after you changed all the icon files in the settings? This always happens on IOS from the icon being cached on the device. Deleting the app or rebooting the device will fix this.

Comment: I Reboot my device and icon shows correctly. Thanks @Doug Rudd.

Comment: I have the same problem, it must be a bug, I noticed that Contents.json is with the path of the default images of the deplhi, it does not respect the deployment configuration